# A "Rigorous" proof for this seemingly obvious proposition.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In mendelson logic textbook , there is this proposition,(I will replace some letters to make it easier to read)

*"If $P$ is a tautology containing as statement letters $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ and $Q$ arises from $T$ by substituting statement forms $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ for $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n,$ respectively, then $Q$ is a tautology;that is, substituting in a tautology yields a tautology"*

This proposition seems way too obvious too me. Then I wondered, is there a rigorous proof of this proposition. There was a proof in the textbook:

"*Assume that $P$ is a tautology. For any assignment of truth values to the statement letters in $Q$, the forms $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ have truth values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ (where each $x_i$  is $T$ or $F$). If we assign the values $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ to  $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n,$ respectively, then the resulting truth value of $P$ is the truth value of $Q$  for the given assignment of truth values.Since $P$ is a tautology, this truth value must be $T.$ Thus, $Q$ always takes the value $T$.*"

The proposition itself is perfectly understandable and it is a very useful proposition(Maybe even too obvious for me). But the proof seems to be not even slightly understandable to me for some reason. I didn't found any other proofs for this theorem anywhere. Is there a better proof for this theorem or I am missing something? (Maybe the proposition is so obvious that proving it is impossible?)

Edit:I just noticed that when I said "I will replace some letters to make it easier to read" then that means "this **proposition** will stay true nomatter if i replace some symbols". But the **proposition** itself is "this **proposition** will stay true no matter if i replace some symbols". So it is like a propositon inside itself.So in shorter words, I am applying this proposition without even proving it in the first place. This is by far the weirdest part about this proposition to me.

Comment: The proof in the textbook is rigorous.

Comment: A tautology is **ALWAYS** true, i.e. every line of the truth table outputs the TRUE value. IF we replace e.g. $p$ with formula $A$ whatever, what truth values $A$ can have? Either TRUE or FALSE; but in both cases the corresponding lines of the truth table we have true as output.

Comment: I agree with you, and on occasion I've seen things like this myself, namely where being able to intuitively grasp the correctness of a proof seems to require essentially the same "metalogic-comprehension awareness proficiency" that one would need to in order to initially intuitively grasp the correctness of the result itself. The result itself, of course, does say something meaningful about the formal language, since you can use the result itself to deduce the tautology'ness of some wff's by immediately recognizing them as "instances" of known tautologies.

Comment: What should I do if I find myself in this kind of weird situation when trying to prove a proposition "rigorously" ? Thanks for your thoughts about this problem.

Comment: One of the difficulties I used to have (and still do to some extent) is that, when working at this "level of intuitive obviousness", intermediate level logic texts (Mendelson level) bring ideas of functions and variable substitution in functions onto the scene supposedly (or at least many readers will think so) to provide more rigor. However, using functions and such to provide these notions of unique output'ness and meta-linguistic variable usage seem to me, if anything, further removed from "intuitive obviousness" than the things they are trotted out to provide rigor for. **(continued)**

Comment: For example, the result you gave that Mendelson proves basically relies on the observation that, if instead of directly assigning each letter of the tautology with exactly one of 'T' or 'F', we introduce an extra step in which a wff replaces the letter, and then observe that when all the letters in all the replacement wff's are each assigned exactly one of 'T' or 'F' (this being a consequence of the definition of (or a theorem about?) "wff"), then each of the replacement wff's get assigned exactly one of 'T' or 'F'. **(continued)**

Comment: I don't see how introducing functions into this adds rigor. What it does add is a shorter and possibly less ambiguous "English language description" of the idea, ASSUMING that the reader is fully conversant with the intuitive notion of a function (belongs in the metalogic language), which incidentally is conceptually different from the formalization of "function" (belongs in the formal logical language) that appears later in the mathematical logic and set theory development of Mendelson's book. **(continued)**

Comment: Lets say "substituting in a tautology yields a tautology" is a proposition.How can you prove that it works for any letters(Like A,B,Greak letters,Arabic letters)?you have to **assume** that "substituting in a tautology yields a tautology" is true.So to me , it seems like I can't prove this theorem for any letters with first assuming the theorem is true.

Comment: To me, the intuitive "non-rigor" background needed to understand replacing a letter with a letter-sequence, and <<under true/false assignments each of the letters becomes exactly one of 'T' or 'F'>> is probably less than the "non-rigor" background needed to understand what it means to be a function and other such notions used to seemingly provide rigor into this process. Indeed, I suppose we could consider replacing some of the original letters with singleton letter-strings (in the sense that $x$ is sometimes replaced with $\{x\}),$ thereby allowing for some letters to not be replaced.

Comment: Is it ok to assume "substituting in a tautology yields a tautology" as some sort of **axiom** and build up logic on it ? (I know this **axiom** is NOT the same thing as general logic axioms taught in textbooks. Here , I mean axiom as "human common sense".)

Comment: I think it's not specifically "substituting in a tautology yields a tautology" that is at the (present) ground level, but rather uniqueness of readability of symbols, permanence of symbols, the notion of replacing letters with wff's producing a wff (actually, this is typically proved, and is probably a bit less intuitively obvious than the tautology issue), etc. I've read others wonder (and I myself have wondered) whether sufficiently advanced alien civilizations would ignore our attempts to communicate based on math ideas because everything we know is like this Mendelson result to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116686/discussion-between-prithu-biswas-and-dave-l-renfro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

Maybe, a more lengthy approach can help, considering the case of a single atom $p$.

Let $F$ a formula and let $p$ a propositional symbol occurring in $F$. This means that the formula is a truth-function $F(p)$: for every truth value assigned to $p$, the truth table corresponding to $F$ will outputs a truth value.

But $F$ is a *tautology*: thus for every assignments of truth values to atoms, the truth table will produce the value TRUE.

Consider now the formula $F' := F[A/p]$, where $A$ is a formula whatever. Irrespective of the "form" of $A$, every assignment will output either TRUE or FALSE as truth value for the formula.

Thus, when $A$ is evaluated to TRUE, we have to consider the lines in the original truth table for $F$ where $p$ is evaluated to TRUE. Due to the fact that $A$ is a *tautology*, in those lines the formula $F$ has value TRUE; thus also $F'$ will have TRUE in those lines.

But also when in the original truth table for $F$ the atom $p$ is evaluated to FALSE, the corresponding lines for formula $F$ have value TRUE; thus also $F'$ will have TRUE in those lines.

The argument can be iterated, taking into account that a formula is an expression of *finite* length and thus only a finite number of atoms occurs into it.